# What is new in SQL Server 2012 regarding casting in ISNULL()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, types, type-conversion, casting

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server database from 2005 to SQL Server 2012.

When I detach and attach the database to the new SQL Server 2012 my app works most of time OK.

I only have problems when my app server tries to write (update) columns of type `BIT`. In situations where I have to write or update columns I am getting an error:

> Cannot access field 'my_column_typ_bit' as type of Integer

The code that executes that statement looks like:

```
<sequence name="ListaArtikalaSingle-update-artikal" type="script">
    <SQL>
    update art 
    set
        sifra = :sifra ,
        naziv = :naziv ,
        naziv_strani = :naziv_strani ,
        sifra_dob = :sifra_dob ,
        naziv_fiskalni = :naziv_fiskalni ,
        jm = :jm_id ,
        tbr_id = :tbr_id ,
        car_stp = :carinska_stopa ,
        trosarina = :trosarina ,
        opis = :opis ,
        vrsta_id = :vrsta_id ,
        podvrsta_id = :podvrsta_id ,
        rg_id = :rabatna_grupa_id ,
        vaga = :vaga ,
        konsignacija = IsNull( :konsignacija ,0) ,
        ambalaza = IsNull( :ambalaza ,0) ,
        proizvod = IsNull( :proizvod ,0) ,
        nusproizvod = IsNull( :nusproizvod ,0) ,
        materijal = IsNull( :materijal ,0) ,
        par_id = :par_id ,
        user_id = (
            case when :user_id = 0 
                then user_id 
                else :user_id 
            end) ,
        ts = GetDate(),
        podgrupa_2 = :podgrupa2_id ,
        faktor_palete = :faktor_palete ,
        faktor_pakovanja = :faktor_pakovanja ,
        za_narudzbu = :za_narudzbu,
        dani_nabave = :dani_nabave,
        dani_nabave_opt = :dani_nabave_opt ,
        dani_pro_avg = :dani_pro_avg ,
        auto_minopt = :auto_minopt ,
        car_tar_br_id = :car_tar_br_id ,
        car_faktor = ISNULL( :car_faktor ,1) ,
        vaga_id = ISNULL(vaga_id , :vaga_id ),
        car_sifra = :car_sifra ,
        naknada_id = :pov_nak_id ,
        tezina = :tezina ,
        stp_kalo_mal = :stp_kalo_mal ,
        stp_kalo_mat = :stp_kalo_mat ,
        stp_kalo_vel = :stp_kalo_vel ,
        jm_izv_id = :izv_jm_id ,
        jm_izv_koef = :izv_jm_koef ,
        drz_pod_id = :drz_pod_id ,
        deklaracija_id = :deklaracija_id ,
        aktivan = IsNull( :aktivan ,1) , --This is my BIT COLUMN
        gift = IsNull( :gift ,0) ,
        vaga_public = IsNull( :vaga_public ,0) ,
        vaga_pub_id = :vaga_pub_id
    where
        id = :id
    </SQL>
</sequence>
```

This part of the code works under SQL Server 2005 - why does it not work under SQL Server 2012?

My database is set to compatibility level: SQL Server 2005 (90).

I tried to change collation of database to match with SQL Server.

I'll try to capture trace of this query to see how my app sending this `BIT` (boolean) type.
I am pretty sure that there is sent as integer 1 to database.

I prefer to make changes in the server layer so I do not have to go through a lot of XMLs like this to explicitly casting integers to bits.

Is there anything that I can do to my database for it to once again accept 1 as boolean?

Digging deeper I realized that there is only issue when using `ISNULL()` function.

I replaced `isnull( @bit_typ, 0)` with only `@bit` and my query passed well.

Is there backward compatibility for `ISNULL` function on SQL Server 2012?

Comment: ISNULL() is still supported in SQL 2012. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: What is this XML that you are showing us and how are you using it?  Specifically, I am asking what facility/language is this?  SQL Server doesn't directly execute XML AFAIK, so this must be part of some other facility.

Comment: @SebastianMeine Cannot access field 'my_column_typ_bit' as type of Integer

Comment: @RBarryYoung That is delphi app

Comment: That is a DELPHI error, not a SQL Server error. Have you changed anything on the DELPHI side?

Comment: @SebastianMeine You beat me to it, that's exactly what I was going to say ... :-)

Comment: @SebastianMeine Unfortunately I can't change DELPHI by itself I am able only to changing these XML-s, and connection strings. I am pusled why that works under sql2005 and do not work under 2012

Comment: @downoters and @ closers Why closing ?

Comment: Do you know what data access technology is used in the Delphi app?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I think it is ADO my connection stigs become whit Provider=SQLNCLI11.0; That app is based on http://www.astatech.com/support/servers.htm

Comment: Have you considered changing **IsNull( :aktivan ,1)** to **IsNull( :aktivan ,*0x1*)**? I don't speak Delphi, but it could be a data type precedence issue.

Comment: @RLF I can pass through with isnull(:aktivna ,cast(1 as bit)) but I have more than 500 queries like this

Comment: @adopilot I understand your problem with the solution, although if the columns are few enough, you might be able to script the change to run against your XML strings.

Comment: There is a diff in how parameters automatically gets the datatype. Against SQL Server 2012 the param is integer when used with isnull and it is boolean when connected to SQL Server 2008. I don't know why (yet) but you can fix it with `isnull(:ParamName, cast(1 as bit))`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You asked right question too bad that we are on wai, dba sucks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 there is a new stored procedure that can be used to get the datatype for parameters [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260.aspx). The driver SQLNCLI11.0 uses that stored procedure when connected to SQL Server 2012.

The older drivers and when SQLNCLI11.0 connects to SQL Server 2008 or earlier it uses [set fmtonly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) to execute a query to check the datatype of the column used in the predicate.

For a query that looks like this:

```
select name from unit where active = isnull(:x, 1)
```

SQLNCLI11.0 against SQL Server 2012 executes this to get the data types for the parameter `:x`.

```
exec [sys].sp_describe_undeclared_parameters N'select name from unit where active = isnull(@P1, 1)'
```

Result:

```
parameter_ordinal name   suggested_system_type_id suggested_system_type_name   
----------------- ------ ------------------------ -----------------------------
1                 @P1    56                       int
```

Using the older drivers it looks like this instead to get the data type from the column that is used:

```
set fmtonly on select active from  unit where 1=2 set fmtonly off
```

If you rewrite your query to use `isnull(:x, cast(1 as bit))` then `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters` will return the data type for the parameter as `bit`.

The rewrite suggested in comment by @RLF `IsNull( :aktivan ,0x1)` will also work.

Another way is to set `DataTypeCompatibility=80` in your connection string. Then SQLNCLI11.0 will also use `set fmtonly` to get the data type for parameters. [Using ADO with SQL Server Native Client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx)